# how to swap elements on React Three Fiber / ThreeJs

Tags: three.js, use-state, react-spring, react-three-fiber

I have this Card component, when clicked it activates and expands the block. wanted to click on one and then the other they switch positions.
something like:

```
// Initial Board
1,1,1,1,
2,2,2,2,
3,3,3,3,
4,4,4,4,
```

and not alowing to same number on line. Row, Column or Main Diagonal.
to be finished ordering the blocks like:

```
// win condition for Board 
1, 2, 3, 4,
4, 3, 2, 1,
2, 1, 4, 3,
3, 4, 1, 2,
```

```
// the Card component
const Card = ({locale, args, color, speed}) => {
  const mesh = useRef(null)
  useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01));

  // expand state of the mesh. change size on click event
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  const props = useSpring({ 
    scale: expand ? [1.4, 1.4, 1.4]: [1,1,1],
  })

  return (
    <a.mesh 
      onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)} 
      scale={props.scale} 
      castShadow 
      position={locale} 
      ref={mesh}>
          <boxBufferGeometry attach='geometry' args={args} />
          <MeshWobbleMaterial attach='material' color={color} speed={speed} factor={0.6}  />
    </a.mesh> 
  )
}
```

```
// its rendering inside Canvas from react-three-fiber
   <Card locale={[-2, 1, -2]} color={'navy'}  speed={6} />
          <Card locale={[0, 1, -2]} color={'navy'} speed={6} />
          <Card locale={[2, 1, -2]} color={'navy'}  speed={6} />
          <Card locale={[4, 1, -2]} color={'navy'} speed={6} />

          <Card locale={[-2, 3, -2]} color={'teal'}  speed={3} />
          <Card locale={[0, 3, -2]} color={'teal'} speed={3} />
          <Card locale={[2, 3, -2]} color={'teal'}  speed={3} />
          <Card locale={[4, 3, -2]} color={'teal'} speed={3} />
          
          <Card locale={[-2, 5, -2]} color={'blue'}  speed={9} />
          <Card locale={[0, 5, -2]} color={'blue'} speed={9} />
          <Card locale={[2, 5, -2]} color={'blue'}  speed={9} />
          <Card locale={[4, 5, -2]} color={'blue'} speed={9} />
          
          <Card locale={[-2, -1, -2]} color={'aqua'}  speed={2} />
          <Card locale={[0, -1, -2]} color={'aqua'} speed={2} />
          <Card locale={[2, -1, -2]} color={'aqua'}  speed={2} />
          <Card locale={[4, -1, -2]} color={'aqua'} speed={2} />
```

github link is here: https://github.com/iagokrt/board-game-threejs
i'm coming up with a dumb logic for the board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is far more complex than a standard stackoverflow answer, so I answer part of it only. The animation part was the most interesting for me, so I solved that problem.

If you want to swap cubes on the board, you must animate by their x,y position. So I added the x,y coordinates to the useSpring, it will use the locale property. You must add an interpolate function where you want to use them in the mesh position property.

```
const Card = ({ locale, args, color, speed }) => {
  const mesh = useRef(null);
  useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01));

  // expand state of the mesh. change size on click event
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  const props = useSpring({
    scale: expand ? [1.4, 1.4, 1.4] : [1, 1, 1],
    xy: [locale[0], locale[1]]
  });

  return (
    <a.mesh
      onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}
      scale={props.scale}
      castShadow
      position={props.xy.interpolate((x, y) => [x, y, locale[2]])}
      ref={mesh}
    >
      <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={args} />
      <MeshWobbleMaterial
        attach="material"
        color={color}
        speed={speed}
        factor={0.6}
      />
    </a.mesh>
  );
};
```

This way if you change the locale property of the Card component then it will animate the new position.

I created a little example. I change the locale in a timer and you can see that it swaps with animation.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tree-fiber-board-5mbns?file=/src/App.js